# Lisp error: code contains a dotted list, ending with

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Trying to compute B^e and getting the weird error

```
*** - code contains a dotted list, ending with B
```

code:

```
(defun fast-power (B e)
  (cond(zerop e) B
    (t (fast-power(* B B)(- e 1)))
  )
)
(write(fast-power 6 3))
```

Comment: formatted code would make it easy to see that you are missing some parens, it should be `((zerop e) B) ...`

Comment: If you have a conditional with exactly one test, there's an expression for that which is easier to use than `cond`: `if`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't want to "do homework", but there are multiple issues here, but you probably intended something like this:

```
(defun fast-power (B e)
    (cond
        ((zerop e) 1)
        (t (* B (fast-power B (1- e))))))

(print (fast-power 6 3))
;; Should show "216"
(print (fast-power 3 6))
;; Should show "729"
```

So, a few comments:

1. Please avoid putting closing parentheses on a new line the way you might be used to putting curly braces on a new line, it's idiomatic to close them "all at once"
2. `cond` requires a certain layout of parentheses, it's always `(cond (condition-1 expression-1) ... (condition-k expression-k))` and so on. The syntax error you got was because this rule was violated; you can always [lookup basic syntax](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_cond.htm).
3. A minor nit: `(+ 1 x)` and `(- 1 x)` can always be better expressed using the [builtin increment/decrement operators](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_1pl_1_.htm), `(1+ x)` and `(1- x)`.
4. Finally, while this is a *natural* recursive function, and the existence of `fast-power` within the body of `fast-power` in your example indicates this, the original example was wrong in both the base condition (the returned value should be 1 when `e` is 0) and the recursion step (you want to multiply `B` with the "next lower value" of `e`).

Answer (score 2):

Correct use of `cond`:

```
(cond
  (predicate consequent ...)
  (predicate consequent ...)
  (t alternative))
```

Notice that all terms are lists. Look at your code again:

```
(cond
  (zerop e)                         ; if the variable zerop is true, then evalaute e
  B                                 ; not a correct term! this will fail!
  (t (fast-power (* B B) (- e 1)))) ; an ok alternative
```

Answer (score 1):

In Common Lisp, a proper list is made up of zero or more cons cells, with a terminating `nil`. The atom `nil` by itself is a zero length proper list.

An improper list is one which is terminated by an atom other than `nil`.

In some situations, an atom other than nil, **by itself**, is kind of considered to be a list.

For instance, look: we can append the proper list `(1 2 3)` with `4`, which effectively behaves as an improper list of length 0:

```
(append '(1 2 3) 4) -> (1 2 3 . 4)
```

Many standard library functions are defined as working only on proper lists. For instance `mapcar`. Look what happens when we feed `mapcar` the number 4 instead of a list:

```
[3]> (mapcar #'identity 4)

*** - MAPCAR: A proper list must not end with 4
```

The error message is effectively saying that, yes, we did pass a list, but it's an improper list which ends with 4! **So the error message will be confusing to you  if you don't think of 4 as a zero length list terminated by 4.**

The upshot is that this sort of confusing error message can occur if you give your Lisp implementation some bad syntax. Lisp systems don't always provide a perfect analysis of mangled syntax with pertinent diagnostics. Sometimes what happens is that a list expression is expected in some spot of the syntax, and that piece of the syntax is blindly fed into some function which processes it; then a mysterious error message occurs if an atom is present in place of the list.

E.g. we can illustrate this in our own macro:

```
[1]> (defmacro user-unfriendly-let (bindings &body form)
       (let ((vars (mapcar #'car bindings)))
         ;; et cetera
         ))
USER-UNFRIENDLY-LET
```

Here, our `user-unfriendly-let` macro expects the `bindings` argument to be a list. It blindly feeds it to the `mapcar` function without any error checking. And so we get:

```
[2]> (user-unfriendly-let ((a 3)) a)  ;; okay
NIL
[3]> (user-unfriendly-let a a) ;; oops confusing error!

*** - MAPCAR: A proper list must not end with A
```

Usually the standard macros in a Lisp system have decent error reporting; but sometimes things are neglected and an error is detected by way of lower level functions getting unexpected data as a result of the bad syntax.

User-defined macros will greatly vary in quality in this regard. It depends on the attitude of the programmer toward the macro and its intended use and audience.

The behavior you're seeing is peculiar to CLISP. Note that it's different between when we present the badly formed `cond` for immediate evaluation versus if we put it into a function:

```
$ clisp -q
[1]> (cond B)

*** - COND: clause B should be a list
The following restarts are available:
ABORT          :R1      Abort main loop
Break 1 [2]> 
[3]> (lambda () (cond B))

*** - code contains a dotted list, ending with B
The following restarts are available:
ABORT          :R1      Abort main loop
Break 1 [4]>
```

So you see the CLISP `cond` operator itself does have a decent diagnostic: `clause B should be a list`. But somehow due to the way the `cond` is processed when in a function body, CLISP takes a "detour" around this nice error check and we get a cryptic error message.  It looks like a bit of a bug, in other words. The intent to diagnose "should be a list" is accidentally thwarted.